# Add blog to StackExchange drop-down menu?

Tags: feature-request, blog

I just noticed that [CrossValidated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) has a [blog on BlogOverflow](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/). When you are registered on CrossValidated SE and you go to that site, the **StackExchange drop-down menu** at the top of the page does not only contain links to the meta site and the chat (in addition to a logout link) but also a **link to the blog**.

Would this also work for our blog or does this only work for blogs hosted on BlogOverflow?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, that link is only present for Blogoverflow blogs - all of the sites (that I've checked) on [this list](https://stackexchange.com/blogs) have the extra blog link, but Worldbuilding (their blog is on Medium like ours), for example, does not have that link.

Comment: See my [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287921/340816) on Meta SE.